# Can I use an implicit class name in Dart?

Tags: dart, with-statement, language-construct

Is there any way to avoid having to explicitly specify a class name in Dart, when using it multiple times?

Let's say I have something like

```
class VehicleType{
    static const int BICYCLE    = 0;
    static const int CAR        = 1;
    static const int BUS        = 2;

    // ... etc ...      
}



class VehicleGroup{ 
        static List<int> YEARLY_INSPECTION =[ 
            VehicleType.CAR,
            VehicleType.BUS
        ];

        static List<int> REQUIRES_LICENSE =[
            VehicleType.CAR,
            VehicleType.BUS
        ];

        static List<int> NO_MINIMUM_AGE =[
            VehicleType.BICYCLE
        ];

        // ... etc ...
}
```

Is there any way I can avoid having to explicitly specify `VehicleType.` for every member in a group? I'm thinking something like the `with` statement that is available in some other languages like Javascript, Visual Basic and Object Pascal .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there's any shorter way of specifying that.  The class name (or you could have used an `enum` here if you didn't care about values) scopes the identifiers so that you won't have collisions.